# Authorization not working for not default guards

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have two authenticable model on my Laravel5.2 App. Admin and Client

the default guard set on my app/config.php is admin.

seems that Laravel authorization is not working for my Client model ! it's only working for the default guard (admin)

Also I tried using authorizeForUser method but still no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: what functions are you using for admin and client authentication ?

Comment: I use Laravel' native auth. Auth::guard('admin') and Auth::guard('client')